# Horizontal alignment of x-scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used ggplot to output two pictures. They share the same x-scale.

[image]

The problem is that the two x-scales don't align accurately. I wonder which argument should I use to get the horizontal alignment of the two x-scales.

Comment: I used ggplot2 to output two pictures in one paper. Both of them share the same x-scale.

The problem is that the two x-scales don't align accurately. I wonder which argument should I use to get the horizontal alignment of the two x-scales.

Attached below is the plot. Many thanks for the kind help!

Best Cheers Chenxi

Comment: please share the data and code you used to produce the plot : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4132844

Comment: you need to use `+ facet_grid()` for generating the plot with more than one panel in one figure. the option `scale = "free_y"` allows you to use separate scales for y-axis.